# Libsyn RSS with Google Feed

Tags: javascript, rss, feed, google-feed-api

I'm using google feeds API to read RSS-feeds from Libsyn.

As i've noticed Google parses the feed itself and therefore excludes a lot of stuff.
Is there any way to change this so that it would include an image link included in the RSS-feed?

```
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed('http://podiet.libsyn.com/rss');
    feed.setNumEntries(25);
    feed.load(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

It's all working perfectly fine except the fact that some of the things in the feed are excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
feed.setResultFormat(google.feeds.Feed.MIXED_FORMAT)
```

Then the image tags will be included. They can be extracted like this for example:

```
var feed = new google.feeds.Feed('http://podiet.libsyn.com/rss');
feed.setResultFormat(google.feeds.Feed.MIXED_FORMAT);
feed.setNumEntries(25);
feed.load(function(result) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        var itunesImageUrl = entry.xmlNode.getElementsByTagNameNS(
        'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd', 'image')[0].
        attributes.getNamedItem('href').value;
        console.log(itunesImageUrl);
    }
});
```